# How can I listen for data being received and send data at the same time with sockets in python 3

Tags: python, sockets, messaging

I can't send and receive data at the same time using sockets in python

I can't think of anything to do to fix it.

```py
#Server
import socket
import time
host = socket.gethostname()
port = 1222
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((host, port))
s.listen(5)
cs, address = s.accept()
print("connected {0}".format(str(address)))
while True:
    time.sleep(0.5)
    msg = input()
    cs.send(msg.encode("utf-8"))
    data = cs.recv(1024)
    print(data.decode("utf-8"))
```

```py
#Client
import socket
import time
from threading import Thread
host = socket.gethostname()
port = 1222
password = "Moffitt123"
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
while True:
        print('connecting')
        try:
                s.connect((host, port))
        except:
                print('failed')
                time.sleep(1)

        else:
                break

while True:
        datar = s.recv(1024)
        print(datar.decode("utf-8"))
        datas = s.send(input().encode("utf-8"))
```

Can't send multiple messages in a row, one must send then the other sends etc. I want to be able to send multiple messages in a row from either side, and receive them all.

Comment: to send and recevie at the same time probably you would have to run `send` and `recv` in separated `threads` - especially if you want to use `input()` which blocks all code.

Comment: Hey threads doesnt work, The data is received but will not show itself until after the input is submitted, I ended up doing two seperate scripts one for input and one for output